# My sqlcmd bcp command keeps returning "incorrect syntax near '.'

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, bcp

I am trying to copy one table from database `Student` to database `Tmp`. To do so, according to our lab - we must first export the table (called `lab4`) into a txt file.

I am trying to do with on the command line using

```
sqlcmd -S Desktop-***\SQLEXPRESS -Q "bcp Student.dbo.Lab4 out Lab4.txt@
```

But I keep getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does your exercise tell you or require you to use sqlcmd? That appears to be a level of complication you are not ready to address. The primary issue is that you consider bcp to be a tsql command. It is a completely separate cmd line utility program. Open a command line and type "bcp" to see if it is installed. Then follow your instructions.

Comment: @SMor thanks for the answer.. my exercise doesn't specifically tell me to use sqlcmd but I am using databases and tables from SSMS and that is how I believe (?) I access those db's. Sorry if that doesn't make sense, I've been struggling with this class and seem to be fairly behind.